# Number of Outcomes containing same number of Heads and Tails

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose that a coin, containing either H or T, is flipped 10 times. What are the total number of outcomes containing same number of H and T?

I've attempted:

C(10,5) + C(10,5). Is this the right answer?

And what are the number of outcomes containing at least 4 Heads?

My solution: Total number of outcomes: (2)^10. Outcomes not containing 4 heads = C(10,3)

So outcomes containing atleast 4 heads will be: 2^10 - C(10, 3).

Kindly correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question we have that there are 10 events and we want to permute them, accounting for the fact that half must be heads and half must be tails, thus we get:

$$N=\frac{10!}{(5!)^2}=252$$

Alternatively, we could think of this as choosing any $5$ out of the $10$ to be heads, thus we have:

$$N=\binom{10}{5}=252$$

And we see we have the same result. You have the right approach for your second question, you look at the contrary as there are less events to consider, but you also need to take into account the times where there are $2$, $1$ and $0$ heads as well, so we have:

$$2^{10}-\sum_{i=0}^{3}\binom{10}{i}=2^{10}-\binom{10}{3}-\binom{10}{2}-\binom{10}{1}-\binom{10}{0}=848$$

---

In response to your comment: If we examine the case that there are 3 forms for each event to take, and we look at the fact that half of them must be heads, then we have the following numbers of possible events:

$$N=\sum_{i=0}^{5}\frac{10!}{5!(5-i)!(i)!}$$

And the formula becomes significantly more complex than the earlier model. In general, if we have $N$ events and $n$ outcomes, and $n_{i}$ of each type of outcome, then we have the following number of possible combinations:

$$\mathcal{N}=\frac{N!}{n_{1}!n_{2}!\cdots n_{n}!}=\binom{N!}{n_{1},\dots,n_{n}}$$

Where we call $\binom{N!}{n_{1},\dots,n_{n}}$ the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem). If we set the number of the first event at some number $k$, then we have in general:

$$\mathcal{N}=\sum_{n_{2}+\dots+n_{n}=n-k}\binom{N!}{k,n_{2},\dots,n_{n}}$$

Comment: I totally get it. But I do not get the basic idea behind C(10,r). I mean, we have 10 events. And for every event, there could be two possible options, so the number of outcomes, let's say in the form, HHTTTTTTTT, are C(10,2) for Heads. But what if, each event had three options? Would that be C(10, 2) in that case too? Can you please explain it intuitively?

Comment: @user3813179 It's somewhat hard to explain, but it would not be $\binom{10}{2}$; I've updated my answer to the question to elaborate a bit more, let me know if you have any more questions